# How can I run Effective GO source code in my local environment?

Tags: go

I am beginning learn GO, I try to run the Effective GO (https://go.dev/doc/effective_go#multiple-returns) example source code in my local environment(GO 1.18+VS code).
For example

```
func nextInt(b []byte, i int) (int, int) {
    for ; i < len(b) && !isDigit(b[i]); i++ {
    }
    x := 0
    for ; i < len(b) && isDigit(b[i]); i++ {
        x = x*10 + int(b[i]) - '0'
    }
    return x, i
}

for i := 0; i < len(b); {
        x, i = nextInt(b, i)
        fmt.Println(x)
    }
```

Another example:

```
    if fd < 0 {
        return nil
    }
    f := new(File)
    f.fd = fd
    f.name = name
    f.dirinfo = nil
    f.nepipe = 0
    return f
}
```

Very appreciate give some Tips! Thanks in advance!

Comment: you mean you wanted to run that to see the result?

Comment: It seems like you're just asking how to run Go code in Visual Studio Code and these specific examples aren't really relevant.  Is that correct?  Or you're already running them in VSCode and encountered some problem not described here?

Comment: All Go code is run in the same way. Please consult https://go.dev/doc/ on how to do it.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I understand the document omit some not important code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a package main and a main function inside of it

Here is an example of a `main.go` file

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func isDigit(b byte) bool {
  // function implementation here...
}

func nextInt(b []byte, i int) (int, int) {
    for ; i < len(b) && !isDigit(b[i]); i++ {
    }
    x := 0
    for ; i < len(b) && isDigit(b[i]); i++ {
        x = x*10 + int(b[i]) - '0'
    }
    return x, i
}


func main() {
    b := []byte{102, 97, 108, 99, 111, 110}
    for i := 0; i < len(b); {
        x, i = nextInt(b, i)
        fmt.Println(x)
    } 
}
```

To execute run: `go run main.go`